# Equivalent to (requires-channel="https") when using <filter-chain> tags

Tags: spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 3.2.5 in a GWT application. I needed fine-grained control over security so I used the following configuration instead of  element:

```
<beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <filter-chain pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
                <filter-chain pattern="/image/**" filters="none" />
                <filter-chain pattern="/index.jsp" filters="none" />
                <filter-chain pattern="/**/logout" filters="logoutFilter" />
                <filter-chain pattern="/**"
                    filters="securityContextPersistenceFilterWithASCTrue, concurrentSessionFilter, usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, exceptionTranslationFilter, filterSecurityInterceptor" />
           </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

I've omitted particular filter implementations.

I need to force most of filter-chain's above to use https like when using the  tag as in the following example:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/reports" access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https"/>
```

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT 1: adding a ChannelProcessingFilter**

Following @luke answer I modified my code so a channel filter is in the first position of the filter chain:

```
<filter-chain pattern="/**"
    filters="channelProcessingFilter, securityContextPersistenceFilterWithASCTrue, ..." />
```

I also added the following beans configuration:

```
<!-- Ensure https channel -->
    <beans:bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
        <beans:property name="securityMetadataSource">
            <filter-security-metadata-source>
                <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
            </filter-security-metadata-source>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="channelProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter">
        <beans:property name="channelDecisionManager" ref="channelDecisionManager"/>
        <beans:property name="securityMetadataSource">
            <filter-security-metadata-source request-matcher="ant">
                <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL"/>
            </filter-security-metadata-source>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="channelDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelDecisionManagerImpl">
        <beans:property name="channelProcessors">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="secureChannelProcessor"/>
                <beans:ref bean="insecureChannelProcessor"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="secureChannelProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.SecureChannelProcessor" />
    <beans:bean id="insecureChannelProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.InsecureChannelProcessor" />
```

Now the problem is I'm getting an infinite loop after submitting my login form via http. Of course it is the case I want to avoid but an infinite loop is not right. This is the relevant log:

> DEBUG o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy 337 - /j_spring_security_check at
>   position 1 of 6 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'ChannelProcessingFilter'
>
> DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter 134
>   - Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /j_spring_security_check; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL] 2014-10-30 19:47:10,565
>
> DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.c.RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint 55 - Redirecting to:
>   /j_spring_security_check 2014-10-30 19:47:10,567 DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.DefaultRedirectStrategy 36 - Redirecting to
>   '/j_spring_security_check'

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a  [`ChannelProcesingFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/channel/ChannelProcessingFilter.html).

It's best if you just require HTTPS to access all of your site. HTTPS is only really secure if you use it from the start. Ideally also you want to use [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) to communicate that to clients.

Comment: Hi @luke. I'm getting an infinite loop in `RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint 55 - Redirecting to: /j_spring_security_check`. Please have a look at my edit above

Comment: Do you have HTTPS set up correctly? i.e. can you access the app over HTTPS and login without the extra filter?

Comment: Yes, I removed _channelProcessingFilter_ and I could log in using https. I also tested to put _channelProcessingFilter_ back and I could access via plain http. Is all this normal? BTW, the server is Jetty embbeded with GWT Eclipse plugin